# Variable is used before it has been assigned a value

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnCIAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCIAdd.Click

    Dim cistatus, cifn, ciln, cicontact, cieadd, cidoa, ciRD, ciRT, ciRN, ciPPD, ciMOP, ciAmount As String
    Dim i, cicid As Integer

    For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        cicid = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        cistatus = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
        cifn = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
        ciln = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        cicontact = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
        cieadd = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
    Next

    cidoa = DateTimePicker2.Text
    ciRD = txtCIRD.Text
    ciRT = comboCIRT.Text
    ciRN = comboCIRN.Text
    ciPPD = txtCIPD.Text
    ciMOP = comboCIMD.Text
    ciAmount = txtCIAmount.Text



    cmd = "INSERT INTO checkin_info VALUES ('" & cicid & "','" & cistatus & "','" & cifn & "','" & ciln & "','" & cicontact & "','" & cieadd & "',','" & cidoa & "','" & ciRD & "','" & ciRT & "','" & ciRN & "','" & ciPPD & "','" & ciMOP & "')"
    rs.CommandText = cmd
    res = rs.ExecuteReader()
    MessageBox.Show("Entry added!")


End Sub
```

This is my whole private sub, and I get the error like "Variable 'cicontact' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime" same with cistatus, cifn, ciln, cicontact and cieadd
 I don't get this.. I initialization was an error, how would I fix that?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Your `For loop` is redundant. All you end up with is the values from the last row in the datagrid, so you might as well just set `i = Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1` and execute once.

Comment: It reduces its error, one left was a syntax error to the "t" end of Count

Comment: Hey, your problem is simple - you have a loop in which you assign value but there is no guarantee that your loop will ever execute. Therefore this doesn't count as "initialization".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code

```
 Private Sub btnCIAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCIAdd.Click

        Dim cistatus As String=""
 Dim cifn As String="" 
Dim ciln As String=""
Dim  cicontact As String=""
Dim  cieadd As String=""
Dim  cidoa As String=""
Dim  ciRD As String=""
Dim  ciRT As String="" 
Dim ciRN As String=""
Dim  ciPPD As String=""
Dim  ciMOP As String=""
 Dim ciAmount As String=""
        Dim i  as Integer =0
Dim cicid As Integer=0

    cidoa = DateTimePicker2.Text
        ciRD = txtCIRD.Text
        ciRT = comboCIRT.Text
        ciRN = comboCIRN.Text
        ciPPD = txtCIPD.Text
        ciMOP = comboCIMD.Text
        ciAmount = txtCIAmount.Text

        For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            cicid = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            cistatus = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            cifn = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            ciln = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            cicontact = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
            cieadd = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value

        cmd = "INSERT INTO checkin_info VALUES ('" & cicid & "','" & cistatus & "','" & cifn & "','" & ciln & "','" & cicontact & "','" & cieadd & "',','" & cidoa & "','" & ciRD & "','" & ciRT & "','" & ciRN & "','" & ciPPD & "','" & ciMOP & "')"
        rs.CommandText = cmd
        res = rs.ExecuteReader()
    next
        MessageBox.Show("Entry added!")


    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it. It gives an error like "Explicit initialization is not permitted with multiple variables declared with a single type specifier"

Comment: @KipRussel, so declare everything on single line, but this answer is right to move your insert within the loop. Besides, this is bad practice to declare on one line and assign on the other if these 2 lines are sequential. Declare and init variable on one line

Comment: Ye @T.S.  You need to initialize each variable in single line

Comment: Haha! Thanks! It worked! thanks for the explanation guys
Convention might be a problem, but I'll work on it after this, I'm a newbie in VB.net, its kinda hard to trace the syntaxes..